# Swordfighting extra hits

Tags: sid-meiers-pirates

In Sid Meier's Pirates! while fencing you can sometimes get an extra hit when you complete the jump defense move. The move has you on a rope that swings you to hit your opponent.

What is the probability of this occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a random event, it's timing related.

Much like the 'flourish' of a perfectly timed dance move, you perform a critical hit if you dodge at the exact right moment rather than 'somewhere within the safe window'.